# Does my Ubuntu have module for USB 2.0?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I copy some files between my external HDD and Lenovo T400 laptop. The external HDD is 7 years old and has "USB 2.0" on its enclosure, and the laptop is 3 years old. The copying speed is mostly 8.3MB/sec, and no more than 10MB/sec. I wonder if there is module for USB 2.0 loaded? If not, how shall I get one?

The output of `lsmod | grep hci` is

```
firewire_ohci 40172 0
firewire_core 56906 1 firewire_ohci.
```

I guess both are about firewire not USB.

Note `lsmod | grep HCI` returns nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB 1 only goes up to 12Mb/s = 1.5MB/s raw bus rate (a bit less for the effective rate since the raw rate includes the command overhead). So you are definitely using USB 2. USB 2 is older than Ubuntu anyway.

The module for USB 2.0 support is `ehci_hcd`. I think that all Ubuntu kernels include it as a module, but I'm not sure, it may be included in the kernel image in your version.

You can check what USB controllers you have by running `lspci`; you're likely to see several USB1 controllers and one USB2 controller (USB2 controllers can handle more devices, so most computers can do with a single one). `lspci -v` will show what driver is handling each PCI device.

The easiest way of finding out in detail what the disk is connected to is to run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb` (or whatever the block device is corresponding to the disk). You can also look up the information directly under `/sys` (that's what `udevadm` does); look where the symlink `/sys/block/sdb` points to.

There is also some information in the output of `lsusb -v`. For a hard disk, there'll be a line `bInterfaceClass 8 Mass Storage`. The `bcdUSB` value is the version of the USB protocol: `2.00` for a USB2 device. The bus number identifies which hub the device is connected to (which may be the root hub inside the controller).

Comment: Thanks! (1) Do you mean `ehci_hcd` for USB 2.0 may be built into the kernel, so lsmod doesn't give any information about it? (2)When I run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`, among many reports about `looking at (parent) device ...`, what should I look for?

Comment: @Tim Look at the ones about USB, they'll be near the bottom. When I plug in a USB flash drive on my machine, the next-to-last device has `KERNELS=="usb1"` and `ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"`.

Comment: lsusb is a good command and might help